# 'Undefined reference to `WinMain' ' error on minimal script, Dev-C++

Tags: c, undefined-reference, dev-c++, winmain

I'm new to C and programming.
I'm on Windows 10, I just installed Dev-C++ and I'm learning how to call functions from other files: i wrote this function to sum two numbers, and I call it from the main script.

The problem is that when i compile the func.c file I get the error in title, so if I run the main file it doesn't recognize the "sum" function.
This is the main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h" 
    main(){
      int x,y,s;
      scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
      s = sum(x,y);
      printf("\n%d",s); 
      }
```

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNC_H_INCLUDED

int func(int a, int b);

#endif // FUNC_H_INCLUDED
```

And this is the code of the sum function in a func.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"
int func(int a, int b){
    return(a+b);
}
```

I did read lots of other questions, but they didnt help in my case, or I didnt get the tricky answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate more on "dev-c++", there are multiple different products with that name (each of which with several versions). Also this question might be better suited to a support forum for "dev-c++" as the issue will be to do with mis-configuration of the compiler in the IDE, and/or shipping of the IDE with a broken compiler,  or mis-configuration of your project in the IDE

Comment: You say " i compile the func.c "  , if you are trying to compile an executable using only func.c then you will get the error in the title. Your project needs to contain main.c and func.c , and compile both of them and link

Comment: I did read that I need to compile first func.c, and then main.c to make it work. They are two separate files, I didn't create a "new project". Is that wrong? Sorry If my answer looks weird, it's the first time that I talk about compilers and functions on different files.

Comment: Try reading the IDE documentation, you most likely do need to create a project in order to have a project with multiple .c files . It will be the same in any IDE

Comment: Yes, I needed to create a project which contained more .c/.h files, I thought I had to compile them separately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Embarcadero's Dev-C++. I use their free compiler since it is "portable".

`func.c` and `func.h` both contain a function called `func` while your main file has a function called `sum`, you must have a consistency in the names, you can do `s=func(x,y)` and that should work, but a good practice is doing the opposite and replace `func` in other files by `sum`.
And you must compile the 3 files, compiling 1 or 2 isn't enough.

To compile them using Embarcadero's free compiler:

`C:\path\to\compiler\bcc32x func.c func.h main.c`

It will give you `main.exe` that you can run from the command prompt.

Comment: I renamed "func" in the .c and .h files with "sum".
The header compiles without errors, but compiling func.c gives me the same error as before.
Is it wrong to compile them separately? Is there a way to compile them all together?

I'll download Embarcadero, maybe it will solve it